# how to disable the second select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select id="title0">
   <option value="0">--- disable</option>
   <option value="1"> books</option>
</select>
<button id="save" type="submit">Save</button>

<select id="title1">
   <option value="0">--- disable</option>
   <option value="1"> books</option>
</select>
<button id="save" type="submit">Save</button>
```

my html select code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#title0").change(function (){
          if($(this).val() === "0"){
            $('#save').prop('disabled', true);
          }else{
            $('#save').prop('disabled', false);
          }
        });

$("#title1").change(function (){
          if($(this).val() === "0"){
            $('#save').prop('disabled', true);
          }else{
            $('#save').prop('disabled', false);
          }
        });
});
```

anyone help me? my second select(id=title1) the JavaScript doesn't work. it only effect for the first 1 (id=title0). i want to disable the button of the second select to.

Comment: Your markup is invalid because there are two elements with the same ID `save`.

Comment: i change the id of the second button to #second but it doesn't work.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Are you disabling the button or the select list

Comment: Ikelie Cyril im disabling the button

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVE THANK YOU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your markup is invalid because there are two elements with the same ID `save`.

**Set a different id, i.e:** `save0` and `save1`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#title0").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "0") {
      $('#save0').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#save0').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });

  $("#title1").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "0") {
      $('#save1').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#save1').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="title0">
   <option value="0">--- disable</option>
   <option value="1"> books</option>
</select>
<button id="save0" type="submit">Save</button>

<select id="title1">
   <option value="0">--- disable</option>
   <option value="1"> books</option>
</select>
<button id="save1" type="submit">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your **Buttons** both **have the same ID** ("save").

Perhaps you can change the ID to "save1" and "save2"?

```
<select id="title0">
   <option value="0">--- disable</option>
   <option value="1"> books</option>
</select>
<button id="save1" type="submit">Save</button>

<select id="title1">
   <option value="0">--- disable</option>
   <option value="1"> books</option>
</select>
<button id="save2" type="submit">Save</button>
```

And then you can change your javascript to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#title0").change(function (){
        if($(this).val() === "0"){
            $('#save2').prop('disabled', true);
        }else{
            $('#save2').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });

    $("#title1").change(function (){
        if($(this).val() === "0"){
            $('#save1').prop('disabled', true);
        }else{
            $('#save1').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

---

**Edit:** If you want to have the button disabled on startup, you can add the .change method at the end like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#title0").change(function (){
        if($(this).val() === "0"){
            $('#save2').prop('disabled', true);
        }else{
            $('#save2').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }).change();

    $("#title1").change(function (){
        if($(this).val() === "0"){
            $('#save1').prop('disabled', true);
        }else{
            $('#save1').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }).change();
});
```

This way, you define what is supposed to happen upon the "change" event and then immediately execute it. Upon opening the page, the buttons are disabled. You can also achieve this, if you set the disabled attribute from the beginning.

Comment: thank you for your help your all code is working but when i apply this in to my project the second one button it doesn't disable. maybe there some bug on my .php file. :(

Comment: Have you checked in your Javascript console if it says anything when opening the page (In Chrome, it is the F12 key and then click on 'Console')?

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVE THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP :D